# How to assign one struct to another (C++14)

Tags: c++, struct, c++14, variable-assignment

I am trying to get bluez to run in C++ to be compiled with several other units already written. My adaptions seem OK except I have one final problem of assigning structs.
In bluez git client/main.c there are 7 statements like

```
struct adapter *adapter = list->data;
```

which naturally g++ baulks at: "error: invalid conversion from ‘gpointer’ {aka ‘void*’} to ‘adapter*’ [-fpermissive]".

adapter is declared in my.cpp (my adaptation of main.c) as per the original bluez *unaltered* declaration:

```
struct adapter 
{
    GDBusProxy *proxy;
    GDBusProxy *ad_proxy;
    GDBusProxy *adv_monitor_proxy;
    GList *devices;
};
```

whereas list->data is declared in glist.h as:

```
struct _GList
{
  gpointer data;
  GList *next;
  GList *prev;
};
```

It seems obvious to me that these are two entirely different objects so one cannot be cast to the other (even if structs ever could be manipulated like that).
How can I get past this hurdle? Which element should map to what? There must be some way because the bluez writers published it on github.

Comment: Assuming that `list->data` is pointing to an `adapter` object, then `static_cast<adapter*>(list->data)`?

Comment: As to why such code works for them, bluez is written in C, you're trying the same code in C++ which is stricter about these things.

Comment: Nope! invalid conversion from ‘gpointer’ {aka ‘void*’} to ‘adapter*’ [-fpermissive]. Maybe I don't understand but isn't this an 'a != b' situation? How would a 3 element struct point to a 4 element struct.

Comment: Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. Honestly, it's putting a square peg in a round hole. The programming idioms mismatch. Instead, compile bluez as C and **link it** with your C++ components.

Comment: @dratenik That helps understanding but is there a way of de-strictifying it or should I approach this in an entirely different way.

Comment: "whereas list->data is declared in glist.h as:" No, `list` is a pointer to `_GList`, so `list->data` is a `gpointer`, which your compiler is telling you is an alias for `void*` a.k.a. a "pointer to something, the type of which is not recorded here". Because C lacks parametric polymorphism, its common for generic code to throw type information away.

Comment: Invalid conversion is what you get is you do a plain assignment or initialization, *without* the cast. Did you try the cast I showed in my first comment?

Comment: @Some  Yes but the cast did not work per comment #3 [which is out of sequence to yours]. All my other casts did compile but not these 7. Now will follow the extern suggestion and accept that when it's working.